# How can i know the CA subject name list which loaded in SSL context

Tags: ssl, openssl

I want to get back the ca certificate name list from loaded SSL_CTX()
Is there any APIs provided by openSSL to get back name?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get back the ca certificate name list from loaded SSL_CTX() Is there any APIs provided by openSSL to get back name?

Kind of. A certificate has an Issuer and a Subject. When you say the "CA Name" you are asking for the Issuer. And its usually on the `SSL*`; and not the `CTX*`.

You would perform something like the following. You will have to figure out how to get the certificate you want to print. Below shows you how to do it with the peer's certificate.

```
/* Drops out of a handshake */
SSL* ssl = ...;

/* Get the certificate from the session object */
X509* cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl);

/* Get the issuer name */
X509_NAME* iname = cert ? X509_get_issuer_name(cert) : NULL;

/* Get the subject name */
X509_NAME* sname = cert ? X509_get_subject_name(cert) : NULL;

if (iname)
    print_cn_name("Issuer name", iname);

if (sname)
    print_cn_name("Subject name", sname);

X509_free(cert);
```

And then:

```
/* This prints the Common Name (CN), which is the "friendly" */
/*   name displayed to users in many tools                   */
void print_cn_name(const char* label, X509_NAME* const name)
{
    int idx = -1, success = 0;
    unsigned char *utf8 = NULL;

    do
    {
        if(!name) break; /* failed */

        idx = X509_NAME_get_index_by_NID(name, NID_commonName, -1);
        if(!(idx > -1))  break; /* failed */

        X509_NAME_ENTRY* entry = X509_NAME_get_entry(name, idx);
        if(!entry) break; /* failed */

        ASN1_STRING* data = X509_NAME_ENTRY_get_data(entry);
        if(!data) break; /* failed */

        int length = ASN1_STRING_to_UTF8(&utf8, data);
        if(!utf8 || !(length > 0))  break; /* failed */

        fprintf(stdout, "%s: %s\n", label, utf8);
        success = 1;

    } while (0);

    if(utf8)
        OPENSSL_free(utf8);

    if(!success)
        fprintf(stdout, "  %s: <not available>\n", label);
}
```

---

***IF*** you wanted *Subject Alternate Names (SAN)* for a server certificate, then you might do something like:

```
void print_san_name(const char* label, X509* const cert)
{
    int success = 0;
    GENERAL_NAMES* names = NULL;
    unsigned char* utf8 = NULL;

    do
    {
        if(!cert) break; /* failed */

        names = X509_get_ext_d2i(cert, NID_subject_alt_name, 0, 0 );
        if(!names) break;

        int i = 0, count = sk_GENERAL_NAME_num(names);
        if(!count) break; /* failed */

        for( i = 0; i < count; ++i )
        {
            GENERAL_NAME* entry = sk_GENERAL_NAME_value(names, i);
            if(!entry) continue;

            if(GEN_DNS == entry->type)
            {
                int len1 = 0, len2 = -1;

                len1 = ASN1_STRING_to_UTF8(&utf8, entry->d.dNSName);
                if(utf8) {
                    len2 = (int)strlen((const char*)utf8);
                }

                if(len1 != len2) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "  Strlen and ASN1_STRING size do not match (embedded null?): %d vs %d\n", len2, len1);
                }

                /* If there's a problem with string lengths, then     */
                /* we skip the candidate and move on to the next.     */
                /* Another policy would be to fails since it probably */
                /* indicates the client is under attack.              */
                if(utf8 && len1 && len2 && (len1 == len2)) {
                    fprintf(stdout, "  %s: %s\n", label, utf8);
                    success = 1;
                }

                if(utf8) {
                    OPENSSL_free(utf8), utf8 = NULL;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "  Unknown GENERAL_NAME type: %d\n", entry->type);
            }
        }

    } while (0);

    if(names)
        GENERAL_NAMES_free(names);

    if(utf8)
        OPENSSL_free(utf8);

    if(!success)
        fprintf(stdout, "  %s: <not available>\n", label);    
}
```

---

The above was taken from OpenSSL's [TLS client](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) example on their wiki. It also shows you how to print the chain in the verify callback.

Comment: first of all thanks @jww. i have two session. in first session i loaded CA certificate with crl into SSL context. again i created new session but i inherited SSL context from first session means single tone class like that.

there are two situation.
1. if first session CA certificate and 2nd session CA certifcicate are not same
 
2.  if first session CA certificate and 2nd session CA certifcicate are not same

for that i have to check current CA certificate subject name which loaded in SSL context during first session. then i will compare with session two CA certificate subject name..